# Oracle SQL pivot query

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data in a table as seen below:

```
MONTH VALUE

1     100
2     200
3     300
4     400
5     500
6     600
```

I want to write a SQL query so that result is given as below:

```
MONTH_JAN MONTH_FEB MONTH_MAR MONTH_APR MONTH_MAY MONTH_JUN
100       200       300       400       500       600
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Oracle 9i+ supports:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.month = 1 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS JAN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.month = 2 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS FEB,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.month = 3 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS MAR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.month = 4 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS APR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.month = 5 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS MAY,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.month = 6 THEN t.value ELSE 0 END) AS JUN
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

You only list two columns -- something like this should probably be grouped by year.

There is ANSI PIVOT (and UNPIVOT) syntax, but Oracle didn't support it until 11g.  Prior to 9i, you'd have to replace the CASE statements with Oracle specific DECODE.

Answer (score 21):

### Oracle 11g and above

As of Oracle 11g, you can now use the [`PIVOT`](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php#pivot) operator to achieve that result:

```
create table tq84_pivot (
  month number,
  value number
);

insert into tq84_pivot values(1, 100);
insert into tq84_pivot values(2, 200);
insert into tq84_pivot values(3, 300);
insert into tq84_pivot values(4, 400);
insert into tq84_pivot values(5, 500);
insert into tq84_pivot values(6, 600);
--
insert into tq84_pivot values(1, 400);
insert into tq84_pivot values(2, 350);
insert into tq84_pivot values(4, 150);

select 
  *
from
  tq84_pivot
pivot (
   sum (value) as sum_value for
     (month) in (1 as month_jan,
                 2 as month_feb,
                 3 as month_mar,
                 4 as month_apr,
                 5 as month_mai,
                 6 as month_jun,
                 7 as month_jul,
                 8 as month_aug,
                 9 as month_sep,
                10 as month_oct,
                11 as month_nov,
                12 as month_dec)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

***Dynamic Pivot*** for **Oracle 11g+**

There’s no straightforward method for dynamic pivoting in Oracle’s ***SQL***, unless it returns `XML` type results.

For the `non-XML` results ***PL/SQL*** might be used through creating functions of `SYS_REFCURSOR` return type

- With **PIVOT** Clause

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Month_Values RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
     v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
     v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
     v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
  BEGIN
     SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||month||''' AS "MONTH_'||TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(month,'mm') ,'MON')||'"' , ',' )
                    WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY month )
       INTO v_cols
       FROM tab;

     v_sql :='SELECT *
                FROM tab t
               PIVOT
               (
                MAX(value) FOR month IN ( '|| v_cols ||' )
               )';

     OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
     RETURN v_recordset;
  END;
  /
  ```
- With **Conditional Aggregation**

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Month_Values RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
     v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
     v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
     v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
  BEGIN
     SELECT LISTAGG('MAX( CASE WHEN month = '''||month||''' THEN '||value||' END ) AS "MONTH_'||TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(month,'mm') ,'MON')||'"' , ',' )
                    WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY month )                 
       INTO v_cols
       FROM tab;

     v_sql :='SELECT '|| v_cols ||' FROM tab';

     OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
     RETURN v_recordset;
  END;
  /
  ```

and then the function can be invoked as

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Month_Values;
PRINT rc
```

from *SQL Developer*'s command line

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ed1ce4986de6c0a9ee65ea33d543a19)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

how to get pivot of the table

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR (P_name, P_id) IN ((choclate,6) AS choclate_6, (candies,8) AS candies_8, (Biscuits,9) AS Biscuits_9)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).