# Count query from single table

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I have table test having values

```
Status  |      DATE
  X     |   25-11-2012
  X     |   25-11-2012
  Y     |   25-11-2012
  Z     |   25-11-2012
  X     |   26-11-2012
  Y     |   26-11-2012
  Y     |   26-11-2012
  Z     |   26-11-2012
```

I want to display like

```
   DATE      | X | Y | Z |
25-11-2012   | 2 | 1 | 1 |
26-11-2012   | 1 | 2 | 1 |
```

Kindly help me out for the same.

Comment: Have you [tried anything yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? How did it go? What is the code and what errors were you getting or how did the results differ?

Comment: @Ben is right, because if you look at the solution given at your question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582218/oracle-rows-to-column-transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582218/oracle-rows-to-column-transformation) the solution to this problem is only a matter of change some variable names and `sum` to `count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  date_col, 
  count(case when status='X' then 1 end) as X,
  count(case when status='Y' then 1 end) as Y,
  count(case when status='Z' then 1 end) as Z
from your_table
group by date_col;
```