# Convert Row into columns

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, oracle10g, local-storage

how can I convert rows of my table as column value
for eg I have a table a

```
emp id
1
2
3
4
```

and I want my output as

```
1   2   3   4
```

i am also using pivot in oracle and crosstab in postgres but not able to get desired solution as shown above.

Comment: "*not able to get desired solution*" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql or this http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:2648932900346131308

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Rows to Column Transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582218/oracle-rows-to-column-transformation)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [listagg function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm#SQLRF51486). Note you need at least Oracle 11 for this.

Comment: Postgres has `arrayagg`.. worth a mention!

Answer (score 0):

Use this script and change it to your values to get desired results

```
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT emp_id, emp_points
    FROM   emp_data)
    PIVOT  (
                SUM(emp_points) AS sum_emp_points 
                FOR (emp_id) IN (1 AS [1], 2 AS [2],3 AS [3],4 AS [4])
           );
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a general solution, but specific to the data described in the question. It's better to make solutions that generally apply to similar situations without data type or length limits.

Comment: I can provide specific answer only to a specific question with some clear explanation on data.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from (select empno from t7) pivot(min(empno) for empno in (1,2,3,4));
```

Comment: select * from (select emp_id from your_table) pivot(min(emp_id) for emp_id in (1,2,3,4));