# Output in Table format

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a sql table in oracle as below and its name is scope.

```
SPECIALIST          CONTENTS    UPDATE_COUNT
Ram                 Updates           23
Har                 Legis             6
Ram                 Updates           65
```

and i want the output to be formatted in the below format please help me.

```
           Har  Ram Total
Updates 0   88  88
Legis   6   -   6
Total   6   88  94
```

thanks

Comment: <sarcasm> 100% real question. </sarcasm>

Comment: You should edit your question to specify what you already tried to solve your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL pivot query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify which version of Oracle you are using.  If you are in Oracle 11g, then you can use the `PIVOT` function. If not, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.  Here are severl version of how to produce the results:

```
select contents,
  sum(case when specialist = 'Har' then update_count else 0 end) Har,
  sum(case when specialist = 'Ram' then update_count else 0 end) Ram,
  sum(case when specialist in('Har', 'Ram') then update_count else 0 end) Total
from yourtable
group by contents
union all
select 'total',
  sum(case when specialist = 'Har' then update_count else 0 end) Har,
  sum(case when specialist = 'Ram' then update_count else 0 end) Ram,
  sum(case when specialist in('Har', 'Ram') then update_count else 0 end) Total
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71fb7/4)

Or you can use `GROUP BY ROLLUP`:

```
select 
  case when contents is null then 'Total' else contents end contents,
  sum(case when specialist = 'Har' then update_count else 0 end) Har,
  sum(case when specialist = 'Ram' then update_count else 0 end) Ram,
  sum(case when specialist in('Har', 'Ram') then update_count else 0 end) Total
from yourtable
GROUP BY rollup(contents);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71fb7/27)

Or you can use `PIVOT` with a `ROLLUP`:

```
select 
  case when contents is null then 'Total' else contents end contents, 
  sum(coalesce(Har, 0)) Har,
  sum(coalesce(Ram, 0)) Ram,
  sum(coalesce(Har, 0) + coalesce(Ram, 0)) Total
from 
(
  select specialist, contents, update_count
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum(update_count)
  for specialist in ('Har' as Har, 'Ram' as Ram)
) piv
group by rollup(contents)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71fb7/24)