# Obtaining information from 4 tables and manipulate it?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm having a lot of difficulties in manipulating information in order to achieve the desired result. Through a query I join with the following result:

```
   Area     |  ID_AT  |     AT    | TYPE
-----------------------------------------
Informatica |    1    |  Sistemaa |  E
Informatica |    3    | engraçado |  E
Informatica |    3    | engraçado |  I
Gestão      |    2    |   aaaaa   |  I
```

query:

```
select a.Area, c.ID_AT, c.AT, dest.type 
from AREA_AT a
left join AT_C c on a.id_AREA_AT = c.id_AREA_AT
left join dest_atv d on d.id_AT = c.id_at and d.id_uo = c.id_uo
left join CLIE dest on d.id_CLIE = dest.id_CLIE
where id.uo = 1222 
order by a.id_AREA_AT, c.id_at, dest.type
```

But what I want is to create a table in php as follows:

```
   Area     |  ID_AT  |     AT    | E | I
-------------------------------------------
Informatica |    1    |  Sistemaa | X |
Informatica |    3    | engraçado | X | X
Gestão      |    2    |   aaaaa   |   | X
```

In short, what I intend to do here is to show only one table ID ativ, showing that may exist or not type I or E depending on what comes from the query.

Do I have to modify the query to facilitate the work myself? Or will I have to create a fairly complicated algorithm in php to perform this function? Ando here turns hours and still could not find a solution that will can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do a [pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query).  Something like

```
select a.Area, 
       c.ID_AT, 
       c.AT, 
       max( case when dest.type = 'E' then 'X' else null end) E,
       max( case when dest.type = 'I' then 'X' else null end) I
  from AREA_AT a
       left join AT_C c on a.id_AREA_AT = c.id_AREA_AT
       left join dest_atv d on d.id_AT = c.id_at and d.id_uo = c.id_uo
       left join CLIE dest on d.id_CLIE = dest.id_CLIE
 where id.uo = 1222 
 group by a.area, c.id_at, c.at
 order by a.area, c.id_at
```

Note that you won't be able to `ORDER BY` the `a.id_area_at` column if you are not selecting (and grouping by) that column in this formulation.  I changed that to sort by `a.area` instead.

Comment: Perfect :D I did not know it was possible to obtain this result for a query. Thank you very much.

Comment: Another question enjoying your answer. How is it possible to get the dest.id_CLIE knowing that E and I are both X?

Comment: @UZUMAKI - Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand the question.  Are you asking how to retrieve just the row with an `ID_AT` value of 3 from the results of the pivot query?

Comment: No. I'm asking if it is possible to obtain `dest.id_CLIE` (id customers) corresponding to the result of the `id_At` value of 3

Comment: @UZUMAKI - Is the `dest.id_clie` value identical in both of the rows that are getting combined to produce the aggregated output.

Comment: @UZUMAKI - So, then, you want to pivot the results so that you get one row per `id_at` and then return two rows with two different `id_cle` values?

Comment: Right. If I understand the operation of the pivot query, I think it will not be possible. But is possible through another query? Or the best solution is to try to manipulate the results through php.

Comment: Already solved with php. Thank you for any attention given to my problem