# Oracle query to convert multiple column into one column

Tags: oracle

I have 50 column in a table and it returns only one row and I want that one row with 50 column to be displayed in 50 rows and one column.

Can any one suggest me the Oracle query for it?

Comment: I found this link - https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2383085  It is ugly, you will need 50 case/when clauses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4841718/570812

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for one row like this to get only column with values

```
SELECT colvalue 
  FROM
(
  SELECT * 
    FROM Table1
  UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS
  (
    colvalue FOR cols IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, ... col50)
  )
);
```

Sample output:

```
| COLVALUE |
------------
|        1 |
|        2 |
|   (null) |
|..........|
```

If you need column with column names from your pivoted table just ditch the outer select

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS
(
  colvalue FOR cols IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, ... col50)
);
```

Sample output:

```
|  COLS | COLVALUE |
--------------------
|  COL1 |        1 |
|  COL2 |        2 |
|  COL3 |   (null) |
| ..... |......... |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1dc5a/2)** demo

Comment: @user1881820 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Be prepared for a lot of typing :) Oracle has `UNPIVOT` functionality but it wants at least two columns in the result, so it won't work for your situation.

First off, you'll need a counter from 1 to 50. You can query one like this:

```
SELECT LEVEL as Counter FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50
```

If you execute this query you'll get the numbers 1-50 as your result. With that as a basis, here's the full(ish) query:

```
WITH Cols AS (
  SELECT LEVEL as Counter
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50
)
SELECT
  CASE Cols.Counter
    WHEN 1 THEN Col1
    WHEN 2 THEN Col2
    WHEN 3 THEN Col3
    . . .
    WHEN 50 THEN Col50
  END AS myColumn
FROM myTable
CROSS JOIN Cols
ORDER BY Cols.Counter
```

Note that all of the columns must be the same data type, so if you have a mixture of character, number and date you'll need to convert them all to character.

Note that this query assumes *one* row in the table, as mentioned in the question. If there's more than one row you should end with `ORDER BY a-column-that-identifies-the-row, Cols.Counter`.