# Pivot query for Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a query that returns the following resultset:

```
GROUP_ID | ORDER | ID
1        | 1     | 1000
1        | 2     | 1004
1        | 3     | 1005
2        | 1     | 2400
2        | 2     | 2402
3        | 1     | 3000
3        | 2     | 3001
3        | 3     | 3002
```

And I need to turn rows into columns (ORDER values will become columns) like this:

```
GROUP_ID | 1     | 2     | 3 
1        | 1000  | 1004  | 1005
2        | 2400  | 2402  | 
3        | 3000  | 3001  | 3002
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  Also you've mentioned the correct term "pivot", have you tried to write one?  Please edit your post to include your attempts at writing this. Another duplicate would be -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query

Comment: Please ignore this question, the only thing that I needed to do was adding the group_id column in my SELECT clause.