# Group by in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by

I have many rows with the fields `name`, `unit`, `amount`. The rows could be

```
name, unit, amount
========
Some name, A, 100
Some name, B, 300
Another name, A, 400
```

I want to select all the rows but grouped by name.

The unit can be either A or B. I want an output as:

```
name, A_amount, B_amount
============
Some name, 100, 300
Another name, 400, 0
```

So depending on the unit the amount should either be in A_amount or B_amount.

Comment: what you want is a pivot table, there are a lot example on SO. The Solution is also depending on your oracle version. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query

Answer (score 2):

You need a pivot operation on your base table to achieve this result.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT name, unit, amount FROM   table1)
PIVOT (amount AS amount FOR (unit) IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b))
ORDER BY name;
```

This query should work for you. Refer [this tutorial](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) to learn more about pivot operations.

Comment: this is only supported from Oracle 11 upwards

Comment: I get the error message ORA-08634. I'm pretty sure that I use Oracle 11.

Comment: @Jamgreen: people usually don't just know the message for any given error code. You need to include the actual error *message* as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query

/*For query 1*/

```
      Select * from #tblsample A
      inner join #tblsample2 B
       On A.ProductId=B.ProductId
```

/*FOR QUERY 2*/

```
        select * from #tblsample
         except
        select * from #tblsample2
```

/*alternate  way for query 2*/

```
          select * from #tblsample
          where productid NOT IN(
          select * from #tblsample2)
```