# join the column and row values in sql

Tags: sql

I have a two table

```
feedback_1  
questions
```

feedback_1 contains Columns

```
id ,patient_id,date_time,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

`questions` table contains row like

```
2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10
```

I have to join the feedback_1 table and questions like this

feedback_1                          questions

2                                    2

3                                    3

4                                    4

5                                    5

6                                    6

7                                    7

8                                    8

Comment: Please share structure, sample data of both the tables and also state expected result... which DBMS are you using : SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: If you are using Oracle then this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/q/4841718/3898076

Answer (score 0):

This will might help you

```
SELECT 
    id , patient_id,date_time
FROM
    feedback_1 AS F
    INNER JOIN questions AS Q on q.id = f.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you natural join to avoid duplicate columns and rows

```
SELECT *  
FROM feedback_1
NATURAL JOIN questions
```