# Combine master and detail table into one row by combining detail fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, one which is the master the other the details. They have a 1 to many relationship:

```
MasterTable
------------
id (pk)
col1


DetailTable
------------
id (pk)
mid (fk to MasterTable id)
col1
```

An example of how data would look would be as such:

```
MasterTable

ID   
---
1     
2
3
4
5 


DetailTable

ID | MID   | COL1  |
---|-------|-------|
1     1       BIRD     
2     1       DOG                      
3     1       DOG --Duplicates are allowed for the same MID
4     1       CAT
5     2       CAT
6     5       FISH
```

For the detail table the possible values for col1 are:

- BIRD
- DOG
- CAT
- FISH
- MOUSE

I then need to create a query which will layout for each id in the master table to see if they have any of these values. So the final query result would look like this:

```
MasterID | BIRD | DOG | CAT | FISH | MOUSE
-----------------------------------------------------
1           Y     Y      Y
2                        Y
3
4                        
5                              Y
```

So I am collapsing the detail table into one row in the final result. I am unsure how to create this query though.

I was trying something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT MASTERTABLE.ID, 
CASE WHEN DETAILTABLE.col1 = 'BIRD' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END AS BIRD,
CASE WHEN DETAILTABLE.col1 = 'DOG' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END AS DOG, 
CASE WHEN DETAILTABLE.col1 = 'CAT' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END AS CAT, 
CASE WHEN DETAILTABLE.col1 = 'FISH' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END AS FISH, 
CASE WHEN DETAILTABLE.col1 = 'MOUSE' THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END AS MOUSE
FROM MASTERTABLE LEFT JOIN DETAILTABLE ON MASTERTABLE.ID = DETAILTABLE.mid;
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a valid problem statement (although the issue is most likely that it's putting things on different rows, since you're not aggregating anything).  In any case, definite duplicate of [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Comment: I do not think it is a definite duplicate of this. Thanks for the pivot feature. I have read the documentation and they all seem to show how to work on a single level of tables, but not multiple levels such as a master and detail table. If I just had one table, I understand how to construct the query, but I do not understand how to then use the pivot to take a detail table (which has a 1 to many relationship with the master) and combine these detail rows into one row.

Comment: ..... pivot the detail table, then (`LEFT)` join it to the master table?  The primary thing in SQL is that statements are about about data selection/transformation.  Every (sub)query manipulates the representation of the data in some way (which can be used to produce some pretty spectacular results).  The result of a pivot is going to be another "table", which you can refer to as such.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - that argument works exactly the same way in the reverse order. The result of a left join is a set of rows, just like a single base table is. If we can pivot data from a table, we can also pivot data from the result of a join. So we can do the join first, and then do the pivoting. I chose this approach for my Answer because it was much closer to what the OP was doing already. He/she wasn't that far off, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pivoting, whether it is done with the `PIVOT` operator (starting from Oracle version 11.1) or with conditional aggregation (version 10.2 or earlier), works equally well on any set of rows, whether that is a single table, the result of joining two tables, or the result of any other set operation permitted in SQL (another aggregation, a `UNION ALL`, or anything else).

You were pretty close in your attempt. All you have to do is to `GROUP BY MASTERTABLE.ID` (since you want only one row per `MASTERTABLE.ID`) and to take the `MAX` of all those `CASE` expressions: if at least one of them is `'Y'` then the `MAX` is `'Y'`, otherwise it is `NULL`.

So:

In your query, EXACTLY AS IT IS,

- change `CASE .... END as BIRD` to `MAX(CASE ... END) as BIRD`
- add `GROUP BY MASTERTABLE.ID` at the end

Comment: AHH that makes sense. Thanks for the great explanation!