# ORA-00936: missing expression - SQL pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Getting the above error in the IN statement. Can you anyone help?

> ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression
> "
> *Cause:    
> *Action:
>  Error at Line: 32 Column:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            cus_id
          , month_end_date
          , product_group
        FROM
            table_name
    ) PIVOT (
        MAX ( product_group )
        FOR month_end_date
        IN (
            SELECT
                add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate)), - level)
            FROM
                dual
            CONNECT BY
                level <= months_between(last_day(trunc(sysdate)), add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate)), - 6))
        )
    )
```

Comment: The list of columns for the `IN (...)`  can't be dynamic. You must specify each output column

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE):

> **subquery**
> A subquery is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword. When you specify a subquery, all values found by the subquery are used for pivoting. The output is not the same cross-tabular format returned by non-XML pivot queries. Instead of multiple columns specified in the pivot_in_clause, the subquery produces a single XML string column.

In Oracle SQL you have to specify exact column names in `pivot`. This is because parser uses them at semantic checks and there no any way to specify dynamic column name in plain SQL. Dynamic pivot in Oracle is quite hard to implement because of the same limitations: even table valued function should have predefined structure of its output. You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65618660/2778710) with example of dynamic pivot, but the trick here is the ability of SQL*Plus to print a result of the cursor.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select 
AR_CREDIT,
AR_DEBIT,
AR_NUMBER,
BILL_GENERATION_DATE,
BILL_NO,
CASHIER_ID,
SUBSTR(CHEQUE_NUMBER,1,3) RVC, 
SUBSTR(CHEQUE_NUMBER,4,4) CHECK_NO, 
NVL(CAST(COVERS as NUMBER),0) COVERS,
DEP_CREDIT,
DEP_DEBIT,
FOLIO_TYPE,
GUEST_COUNTRY_CODE,
GUEST_COUNTRY_NAME,
GUEST_CREDIT,
GUEST_DEBIT,
GUEST_NAME,
GUEST_NAME_ID,
MUN_VAT,
NET,
PAYEE_NAME,
PAYEE_NAME_ID,
PAYEE_NAME_TYPE,
PT,
RESORT,
RESV_NAME_ID,
ROOM,

--TAXELEMMINIC,
--TAXELEMVAT,
TRANS_CODE,
trim(TRX_CODE) TRX_CODE,
TRX_DATE,
rtrim(TRX_DESCR) as TRX_DESCR,
TRX_GROUP,
TRX_SUBGROUP,
TRX_NO,
VAT
from EUROTEL_REPORT_fin_trans
where trx_date between :from_date and :to_date

and
   from EUROTEL_REPORT_RES_WBLKNM
WHERE business_date BETWEEN :datefrom AND :DATEto
--WHERE business_date BETWEEN to_date('01/05/2013','dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('31/12/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')

group by  
        RESORT, 
        R_TYPE, 
        ROOM, 
     ---   RESV_NAME_ID, 
       -- GUEST_NAME_ID, 
     ---   GUEST_FIRST_NAME, 
    ----    CUSTOM_REFERENCE, 
        MEAL_PLAN, 
        ARRIVAL_DATE, 
   --     DEPARTURE_DATE, 
        business_date,
        TO_CHAR(BUSINESS_DATE,'yyyy')  ,
        TO_CHAR(BUSINESS_DATE,'MM'),
     -----   TO_CHAR(BUSINESS_DATE,'WW')   ,
        --RT_FACTOR, 
        ROOM_TYPE, 
        ROOM_TYPE_RTC, 
        ROOM_CLASS, 
        MARKET_CODE, 
        SOURCE_CODE, 
        RATE_CODE, 

    -----         GROUP_ID, 
     ---   TRAVEL_AGENT_ID, 
    ---    COMPANY_ID, 
     ---   SOURCE_ID, 
            BOOKED_DATE, 
        --CONFIRMATION_NO, 
        PSUEDO_ROOM_YN, 
        CANCELLATION_DATE, 
        RESV_STATUS, 
        DEDUCT, 
        BLOCK_DEDUCT, 
        
     ---   ALLOTMENT_HEADER_ID, 
        ALLOTMENT_NAME,
        --COUNTRY, 
        --NATIONALITY, 
        COUNTRY_NAME, 
        NATIONALITY_NAME,
        COMPANY,
        TRAVEL_AGENT,
        SOURCE,
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).