# Convert vertical table to horizontal in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table format.

| POLNO | NAME | PRM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12100 | PRMA | 161410 |
| 12100 | PRMB | 0 |
| 12100 | PRMC | 0 |
| 12100 | PRMD | 80 |

I need to convert this table to follow.

| POLNO | PRMA | PRMB | PRMC | PRMD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12100 | 161410 | 0 | 0 | 80 |

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use pivoting logic:

```sql
SELECT
    POLNO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'PRMA' THEN PRM END) AS PRMA,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'PRMB' THEN PRM END) AS PRMB,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'PRMC' THEN PRM END) AS PRMC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN NAME = 'PRMD' THEN PRM END) AS PRMD
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY POLNO;
```