# Get all 1:n records from subtable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table INCIDENTCHAPTER. Each INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID is unique

| INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID | .... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

And this sub-table LABEL. Each INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID must have a Name und Shortname, but the Help is optional. So it looks like this.

| INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID | TEXTTYPE | TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Alert |
| 1 | Shortname | A |
| 1 | Help | Some Helptext |
| 2 | Name | Notification |
| 2 | Shortname | N |
| 2 | Help | Another Helptext |
| 3 | Name | Chapter One |
| 3 | Shortname | 1 |

I have this sql:

```
SELECT
INCIDENTCHAPTER.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID,
N.TEXT AS NAME,
SN.TEXT AS SHORTNAME,
H.TEXT AS HELP
FROM
REM_DBA.INCIDENTCHAPTER
LEFT JOIN LABEL N ON INCIDENTCHAPTER.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = N.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID
LEFT JOIN LABEL SN ON INCIDENTCHAPTER.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = SN.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID
LEFT JOIN LABEL H ON INCIDENTCHAPTER.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = H.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID
WHERE
N.TEXTTYPE = 'Name' AND
SN.TEXTTYPE = 'ShortName' AND
H.TEXTTYPE = 'Help'
```

| INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID | NAME | SHORTNAME | HELP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alert | A | Some Helptext |
| 2 | Notification | N | Another Helptext |

But it only gets me INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID 1 and 2.
Because INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID 3 has no Help.

Whats the correct sql to make it look like:

| INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID | NAME | SHORTNAME | HELP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alert | A | Some Helptext |
| 2 | Notification | N | Another Helptext |
| 3 | Chapter One | 1 |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the filters from the `WHERE` clause to the respective `ON` clauses:

```sql
SELECT ic.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID,
       N.TEXT AS NAME,
       SN.TEXT AS SHORTNAME,
       H.TEXT AS HELP
FROM   REM_DBA.INCIDENTCHAPTER ic
       LEFT JOIN LABEL N
       ON (   ic.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = N.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID
          AND N.TEXTTYPE = 'Name')
       LEFT JOIN LABEL SN
       ON (   ic.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = SN.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID
          AND SN.TEXTTYPE = 'ShortName')
       LEFT JOIN LABEL H
       ON (   ic.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = H.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID
          AND H.TEXTTYPE = 'Help')
```

If you put them in the `WHERE` clause then those values are mandatory and the `LEFT JOIN`s effectively become `INNER JOIN`s as there must be a value that matches the `WHERE` filters.

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE INCIDENTCHAPTER (INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

CREATE TABLE label (INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID, TEXTTYPE, TEXT) AS
SELECT 1, 'Name',      'Alert' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'ShortName', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Help',      'Some Helptext' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Name',      'Notification' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ShortName', 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Help',      'Another Helptext' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Name',      'Chapter One' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'ShortName', '1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID | NAME | SHORTNAME | HELP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alert | A | Some Helptext |
> | 2 | Notification | N | Another Helptext |
> | 3 | Chapter One | 1 | *null* |

---

Or, you could use a single join and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ic.incidentchapter_id,
         l.texttype,
         l.text
  FROM   /*REM_DBA.*/INCIDENTCHAPTER ic
         LEFT OUTER JOIN LABEL l
         ON (   ic.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID = l.INCIDENTCHAPTER_ID)
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(text) FOR texttype IN (
    'Name'      AS name,
    'ShortName' AS shortname,
    'Help'      AS help
  )
);
```

Which gives the same output for your sample data (but would not give the same data if there were multiple rows for a `texttype` in a chapter).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7e391491c9731c29a460b14a6dfe71d9)*