# Aggregate values to separate columns from using WM_CONCAT

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have these tables and values:

Table1:

| AppID | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sample |

Table2:

| AddID | AppID | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Add1 |
| 2 | 1 | Add2 |
| 3 | 1 | Add3 |
| 4 | 1 | Add4 |

With my current code:

```
SELECT app.AppID
       add.Address as Addresses

FROM Table1 app
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT     AppID,
                        REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(Address), ',', '; ') AS Address
            
            FROM Table2
            GROUP BY AppID) add ON app.AppID = add.AppID

ORDER BY app.AppID;
```

I get this output:

| AppID | Addresses |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Add1; Add2; Add3; Add4 |

But how can I possibly have this output instead?:

1. Put the addresses in separate columns instead of being joined in one column
2. Only limit the column for address to only 3.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| AppID | Address1 | Address2 | Address3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Add1 | Add2 | Add3 |

I am using Oracle Developer v3.2.10

Comment: can you reformat your question so that the layout of the tables etc is easier to follow

Comment: hello @ConnorMcDonald, already reformatted it. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Comment: hi @astentx, not really...

Comment: But why? What is the issue?

Comment: I have multiple AppID that I am pulling from and each AppID has multiple Addresses. I wanted to limit the Address that I extract to only 3. and I really need help in understanding how i can apply it in the code that I have now (which I placed in my question above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such an output, you don't even need `table1` as all columns are already contained in `table2`. If you apply conditional aggregation, you get the result.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (appid, description) as
  3    (select 1, 'Sample' from dual),
  4  table2 (addid, appid, address) as
  5    (select 1, 1, 'Add1' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 1, 'Add2' from dual union all
  7     select 3, 1, 'Add3' from dual union all
  8     select 4, 1, 'Add4' from dual
  9    )
```

Query:

```
 10  select b.appid,
 11    max(case when b.addid = 1 then address end) address1,
 12    max(case when b.addid = 2 then address end) address2,
 13    max(case when b.addid = 3 then address end) address3
 14  from table2 b
 15  group by b.appid;

     APPID ADDRESS1   ADDRESS2   ADDRESS3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Add1       Add2       Add3

SQL>
```

---

Also, forget that `wm_concat` exists. It is undocumented function and - although it works in certain database versions - once you upgrade to 12c (or higher), your code won't work any more because Oracle **removed** `wm_concat`. Switch to something else (`listagg` if possible, `xmlagg` otherwise).

Comment: i didn't notice this immediately, sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `WM_CONCAT`. It is an undocumented function that was removed in Oracle 12 and no longer exists.

Number the rows using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.AppID,
         Address,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.AppID ORDER BY t2.AddID) AS rn
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
         ON (t1.appid = t2.appid)
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(Address) FOR rn IN (
    1 AS address1,
    2 AS address2,
    3 AS address3
  )
);
```

Or, number the rows and then use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT appid,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN address END) AS address1,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN address END) AS address2,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN address END) AS address3
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.AppID,
         Address,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.AppID ORDER BY t2.AddID) AS rn
  FROM   table1 t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
         ON (t1.appid = t2.appid)
)
GROUP BY appid
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (AppID PRIMARY KEY, "DESC") AS
SELECT 1, 'Sample' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (AddID PRIMARY KEY, AppID, Address) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'Add1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'Add2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'Add3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 'Add4' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | APPID | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2 | ADDRESS3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Add1 | Add2 | Add3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2dc9080bb13cdfdcf624da71291bdf5d)*

Comment: PIVOT is not working with my Oracle SQL version..

Comment: @sellavsert Then use conditional aggregation. The `PIVOT` syntax is available from Oracle 11g (which was released in 2007).

Comment: sorry i just tried the conditional aggregation now, and it worked!! thank you!!!