# need a single/multiple sql query to fetch data as displayed below

Tags: sql, oracle

refernce data in db

| emp_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | 08-09-22 |
| 2222 | 08-09-22 |
| 3333 | 08-09-22 |
| 2222 | 08-09-22 |
| 3333 | 08-09-22 |
| 1111 | 09-09-22 |
| 3333 | 09-09-22 |
| 3333 | 09-09-22 |
| 2222 | 10-09-22 |
| 2222 | 10-09-22 |
| 2222 | 10-09-22 |

expected result

| emp_id | 08-09-22 | 09-09-22 | 10-09-22 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2222 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 5 |
| 3333 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 4 |

Comment: Try searching the Internet for [oracle sql pivot query](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot)

Comment: You want a pivot query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query for example

Comment: try the example queries ,and post what you have tried so far, do ask ' need a query?'

Comment: Pivot and then add the column values to give the total.