# Oracle transform table column to two columns

Tags: oracle, pivot

Let say I have the next table:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | A |
| 2 | 12 | A |
| 2 | 13 | A |
| 2 | 13 | B |
| 3 | 12 | A |
| 3 | 13 | B |

I want to transform it to:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | Value_A | Value_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 13 | 0 | 1 |

- When there is a value A but no Value B, so put 0 in Value B
- When there is a value B but no Value A, so put 0 in Value A

How can I do it in oracle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT ( COUNT(*) FOR value IN ('A' AS Value_A, 'B' AS Value_B) )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID_1, ID_2, Value) AS
SELECT 1, 11, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 12, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 13, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 13, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 12, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 13, 'B' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID_1 | ID_2 | VALUE_A | VALUE_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 13 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 13 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TbKFwPGG)

Answer (score 0):

You could use below solution to get the job done

```sql
select ID_1, ID_2
  , decode(Value_A, null, 0, 1) Value_A
  , decode(Value_B, null, 0, 1) Value_B
from your_Table t
pivot (
max(Value) for value in (
  'A' as Value_A
, 'B' as Value_B  
)
)
order by ID_1, ID_2
;
```

[***demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/ydHG1w8j)