# Populate name,monthly maximum,monthly minimum,monthly average from the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table which got readings on different days in a month. Please help me to populate the name,monthly maximum,monthly minimum,monthly average from the table.

| name | month | data_type | data_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raj | 7 | max | 100 |
| raj | 7 | min | 20 |
| raj | 7 | avg | 80 |
| raj | 7 | max | 90 |
| raj | 7 | avg | 75 |
| raj | 7 | min | 30 |
| raj | 7 | max | 95 |
| raj | 7 | avg | 70 |
| raj | 7 | avg | 65 |
| raj | 7 | max | 85 |
| raj | 7 | max | 96 |
| raj | 7 | avg | 70 |
| raj | 7 | min | 35 |
| raj | 7 | min | 45 |
| raj | 7 | avg | 84 |
| dev | 8 | max | 125 |
| dev | 8 | min | 35 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 50 |
| dev | 8 | max | 120 |
| dev | 8 | min | 20 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 70 |
| dev | 8 | max | 100 |
| dev | 8 | min | 45 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 83 |
| dev | 8 | max | 70 |
| dev | 8 | min | 58 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 95 |
| dev | 8 | max | 110 |
| dev | 8 | min | 60 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 90 |
| dev | 8 | max | 115 |
| dev | 8 | min | 50 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 67 |
| dev | 8 | max | 97 |
| dev | 8 | min | 45 |
| dev | 8 | avg | 84 |

**output should be**

| name | month | month_max | month_min | month_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| raj | 7 | 100 | 20 | 74 |
| dev | 8 | 125 | 20 | 77 |

I tried

```
select name,month,max(data_value) as month_max,min(data_value) as month_min from table
```

which helping some thing. but i unable to figure how to implement logic for monthly average.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt to resolve this yourself, what the result of it is, and how it's different from the result you need.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I tried ' select name,month,max(data_value) as month_max,min(data_value) as month_min from table' which helping some thing. but i unable to figure how to implement logic for monthly average.

Comment: @Jesse updated the question please check

Comment: According to your input table, the month_max value for dev should be 125 not 120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT name, month, 
       MAX(CASE data_type WHEN 'max' THEN data_value END) month_max,
       MIN(CASE data_type WHEN 'min' THEN data_value END) month_min,
       AVG(CASE data_type WHEN 'avg' THEN data_value END) month_avg  
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name, month
ORDER BY name, month
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EMNKSzIU?hide=12).

Comment: wonderful, this should work out. thank you. I never knew we can use case inside of the aggregate functions