# Oracle SQL Produce Multi-Columns From the Same Column With Mutual Rows Values

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, subquery

I have table `element_types` with column `element_type` containing amount types `Basic Salary` and `Housing Allowance`, i want to produce 2 column, one for `Basic Salary` and another for `Housing Allowance`, these types are linked to another table like employees and the values for those types ..etc, so I want to make 2 separate columns and not displaying types and amounts in rows.

```
SELECT .....,       
       (SELECT element_name
          FROM pay_element_types_tl
         WHERE element_name IN ('Basic Salary')) Salary,       
       (SELECT element_name
          FROM pay_element_types_tl
         WHERE element_name IN ('Housing Allowance')) Housing
```

this gives error

> ```
> single-row subquery returns multiple rows
> ```

how can I achieve what I want?

i've tried to use multi-rows subquery using `where` but i want more than a column with different names derived from the same column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `CASE WHEN` use case:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN element_name = 'Basic Salary'
  THEN element_name END AS Salary,
CASE WHEN element_name = 'Housing Allowance'
  THEN element_name END AS Housing
FROM PAY_ELEMENT_TYPES_TL;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DLe7MiLt)

Use aggregation around if required (`MAX`, `MIN` etc., depending on what you need)

Comment: it says ```too many values```

Answer (score 0):

You might use a conditional aggregation to pivot the data as desired like

```
SELECT MAX(CASE
           WHEN element_name = 'Basic Salary' THEN
                element_name
            END) AS Salary,
       MAX(CASE
           WHEN element_name = 'Housing Allowance' THEN
                element_name
            END) AS Housing
  FROM pay_element_types_tl
```

eg. move conditions from the WHERE clause to CASE..WHEN expressions while aggregating the values to prevent generating multiple rows