# Oracle SQL Converting Rows into Columns and Giving them Values from another Table based on Conditions from another Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have table `employees` with column `emp_id` and `emp_name`, table `elements` containing column `person_id` and `element_name` such as `Basic Salary`, and table `values` containing column `value_result` such as `1500` and also contains rubbish data that is not wanted, in order to get rid of it I need to use table `values_type` containing column `value_type`,

```
select element_name , // e.g. Basic Salary
values // e.g. 1500,
emp_name // john


from values,values_type, elements,employees

join elements on elements.emp_id= employees.emp_id
and element_name IN ('Basic Salary', 'Transportation Allowance')
join values on values.element_id = elements.element_id
join values_type on values_type.value_id = values.value_id
and values_type.value_type = 'Amount` // in order to give me desirable values in numbers
```

this works fine, but it will give me 2 rows for each `employee`, one for `Basic Salary` and one for `Transportation Allowance`, what I want is to make 2 columns from `element_name` rows, those are `Basic Salary` and `Transportation Allowance`, then I want to bring the related rows (`values`) from table `values` under each column based on the condition `` types.value_type = 'Amount` `` from table `values_type`, how can I achieve that ?

**sample result**

```
emp_id     element_name                values   
1          Basic Salary                1500
1          Transportation Allowance    200
```

**wanted results**

```
emp_id     Basic Salary                Transportation Allowance
1          1500                        200
```

i've tried to join table `values` 2 times in order to use different conditions on columns :

```
select element_name , // e.g. Basic Salary
v1.values, // e.g. 1500 ( basic salary )
v2.values, // e.g. 200 ( transportation allowance )
emp_name, // john


from values,values_type, elements,employees

join elements on elements.emp_id= employees.emp_id
and element_name IN ('Basic Salary', 'Transportation Allowance')

left outer join values v1 on v1.values.element_id = elements.element_id
left outer join values v2 on v2.values.element_id = elements.element_id

join values_type on values_type.value_id = values.value_id
and values_type.value_type = 'Amount` // in order to give me desirable values in numbers
```

but then i need to join `values_type` to each one:

```
join values_type t1 on t1.values_type.value_id = v1.values.value_id
and t1.value_type = 'Amount` // in order to give me desirable values in numbers

join values_type t2 on t2.values_type.value_id = v2.values.value_id
and t2.value_type = 'Amount` // in order to give me desirable values in numbers
```

which will of course not work, it will give empty results, I've been stuck at this for 2 days now..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Comment: Desired output looks like what would be achieved with a PIVOT query. How are tables ELEMENTS and VALUES related?

Comment: This is a two-step task: generate key-value table (`element_name` and `value` in your case) then do pivot

Comment: astentx i will check it, June7 they are related through ```element_id```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this one

```sql
select emp_id, // e.g. Basic Salary
sum(decode(element_name,'Basic Salary',values,0)) Basic_Salary, 
sum(decode(element_name,'Transportatiion Allowance',values,0)) Transportation_Allowance


from values,values_type, elements,employees

join elements on elements.emp_id= employees.emp_id
and element_name IN ('Basic Salary', 'Transportation Allowance')
join values on values.element_id = elements.element_id
join values_type on values_type.value_id = values.value_id
and values_type.value_type = 'Amount' 
group by emp_id
```