# merge several records with the same call_id into one

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is a `table_verif` table where I need to insert data, here is an example of fields and records for this table:

```
call_id | datetime  |     process_name     | param_1 | param_2      | param_3 | param_ 4 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234567 | 29.12.2022| verification process | greeting| presentation | result  | waiting  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And there is my table **my_table** with entries:

```
call_id  | datetime   |  process_name |       param_1        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1234567  | 29.12.2022 |  complaints   | Establishing contact | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
1234567  | 29.12.2022 |  complaints   | Identification       | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
1234567  | 29.12.2022 |  complaints   | Num specification    | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
1234567  | 29.12.2022 |  complaints   | Data transfer        |
```

I need to translate these four records into a `table_verif` format:

```
call_id| datetime |process_name|    param_1         | param_2      | param_3         | param_4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234567|29.12.2022|complaints  |Establishing contact|Identification|Num specification|Data transfer
```

I took it shortly to param_4, but in practice it starts with param_1 and ends with ..param_9

Comment: You can pivot; but how will you decide what order to put them in - why is 'Identification' param_2 for example, not 1 or 3 or 9? (It also sounds like `table_verif` should be a view of that pivot query, rather than a real table duplicating the data; unless `my_table` is just a temporary staging table.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can [pivot](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-05BB22CD-0F53-4C90-AE84-CE3F88DBD591) a result set (more explanation [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1)), but you need to have a value to pivot on and provide the ordering for the result. For example you could start with a query like:

```
select call_id, datetime, process_name, param_1,
  -- establish some ranking - use your own criteria
  row_number() over (partition by call_id, process_name order by datetime, param_1) as rn
from my_table
```

which with the sample data plus reverse-engineered data from your example `table_verif` row might produce:

| CALL_ID | DATETIME | PROCESS_NAME | PARAM_1 | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | complaints | Data transfer | 1 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | complaints | Establishing contact | 2 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | complaints | Identification | 3 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | complaints | Num specification | 4 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | verification process | greeting | 1 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | verification process | presentation | 2 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | verification process | result | 3 |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | verification process | waiting | 4 |

You may have different criteria to decide the parameter order, perhaps from a look-up table you haven't shown. However you get it, once you have a generated value like `rn` you can use that for the pivot:

```
select *
from (
  select call_id, datetime, process_name, param_1,
    -- establish some ranking - use your own criteria
    row_number() over (partition by call_id, process_name order by datetime, param_1) as rn
  from my_table
)
pivot (
  max(param_1)
  for (rn) in (1 as param_1, 2 as param_2, 3 as param_3, 4 as param_4, 5 as param_5)
)
```

| CALL_ID | DATETIME | PROCESS_NAME | PARAM_1 | PARAM_2 | PARAM_3 | PARAM_4 | PARAM_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | complaints | Data transfer | Establishing contact | Identification | Num specification | *null* |
| 1234567 | 29-DEC-22 | verification process | greeting | presentation | result | waiting | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g2bK4W1L)

You can then use that as an `insert ... select ...` statement to populate `table_verif`, or if this is permanent data then you can turn the query into a view instead of duplicating it.

You could also pivot by listing all the possible `param_1` values in the `in()` clause instead of generating a ranking value, but that would give you a much wider result, and doesn't seem to be what you want here.