# Oracle Database SQL - Turn Column into a row - String values only - PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, syntax-error, oracle-sqldeveloper

| ID (PrimaryKey) | HumanAttribut | attributValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | John |
| 1 | Country | USA |

I want to turn a column into a row

like this:

| ID (PrimaryKey) | Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | USA |

```
SELECT ID, (*pink*) [Name], [Country]
FROM
(SELECT ID, HumanAttribut as Ahuman, attributValue
FROM tableA
WHERE ID = 1
AND HumanAttribut IN ('Name', 'Country')) as SourceTabele
PIVOT
(Max(attributeValue)
For
Ahuman in ([Name], [Country])
) as PIVOT_TABLE
```

I get the error missing expression. Oracle shows me with pink that there is an error.

[pink error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg52g.png)

If someone already posted something similar like this, with easy values like name or country then pls link it to me.

Thanks for the help in advance!

I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT_Z2VP2Z24, but I dont know why my syntax is wrong, I know that something is missing through the error message, but I dont know what I forgot...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query)

Comment: Oracle doesn't use brackets for quoted identifiers, so `[Name]` is an invalid identifier

Comment: And `pivot` clause goes before the `where` clause. See [`SELECT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) statement: `pivot` is part of `table_reference`, which is placed before `where_clause`

Comment: would this be possible? Here I found a website with WHERE, but before PIVOT or is this an error? https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: Where clause in the above link is applied inside a subquery. But I've missed the count of brackets in your code, it is okay in this part. Just remove square brackets and it will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- wrong Syntax, use Oracle db
- syntax railroad diagramm error
- syntax error

I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Oracle does not like HumanAttribut as Ahuman, please try HumanAttribut  Ahuman

You can use not only PIVOT-operator, but the other approach (hope, it will help)

```
WITH CTE(ID,HumanAttribut,attributValue)
AS
(
   SELECT 1,    'Name',     'John' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,    'Country',  'USA' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT C.ID,
 MAX
  (
      CASE
        WHEN C.HumanAttribut='Name'THEN C.attributValue
        ELSE ''
      END
  )NAME,
  MAX
  (
      CASE
       WHEN C.HumanAttribut='Country'THEN C.attributValue
       ELSE ''
     END
  )COUNTRY
  FROM CTE C
 GROUP BY C.ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/AKl-2nK7

Comment: Have to solve this with PIVOT sadly, but nevertheless thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is some examples that can help you

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
PIVOT  (MAX(column_name)
       FOR new_row_name IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'))
```

You can also use the UNPIVOT operator to convert rows into columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
UNPIVOT (column_name FOR new_row_name IN (value1, value2, value3))
```