# I want to use table A and table B for create table C

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

please help me , I want to create table C with using table A and B ,I am new in oracle .what is the idea? how can I write this code ......
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THyxQ.png)

Comment: Please do **NOT** post images of data. Instead provide it as text we can copy/paste (preferably as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that can also be executed).

Comment: Does the question suppose that we need to guess your requirement by looking at the data and column names?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841718/oracle-sql-pivot-query

Answer (score 1):

One option is to conditionally aggregate values (but it also means that table `B` won't help much) (also, `date` is most probably not a column name as it is reserved word, reserved for the `date` datatype so I *renamed* it to `datum`):

```
select a.datum,
  sum(case when a.code = 1 then rate else 0 end) usd,
  sum(case when a.code = 2 then rate else 0 end) eur,
  sum(case when a.code = 3 then rate else 0 end) obp
from a
group by a.datum
order by a.datum;

DATUM              USD        EUR        OBP
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
28-oct-2018       1000       2000       4000
29-oct-2018       2000       3000       5000
30-oct-2018       3000       4000       6000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT a."DATE",
         b.name,
         a.rate
  FROM   A
         INNER JOIN B
         ON (a.code = b.id)
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(rate)
  FOR name IN (
    'USD' AS usd,
    'EUR' AS eur,
    'OBP' AS obp
  )
)
```

or conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT a."DATE",
       SUM(CASE b.name WHEN 'USD' THEN a.rate END) AS usd,
       SUM(CASE b.name WHEN 'EUR' THEN a.rate END) AS eur,
       SUM(CASE b.name WHEN 'OBP' THEN a.rate END) AS obp
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
       ON (a.code = b.id)
GROUP BY a."DATE"
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (code, rate, "DATE") AS
  SELECT 1, 1000, DATE '2018-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2000, DATE '2018-10-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3000, DATE '2018-10-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2000, DATE '2018-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3000, DATE '2018-10-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4000, DATE '2018-10-30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4000, DATE '2018-10-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5000, DATE '2018-10-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 6000, DATE '2018-10-30' FROM DUAL

CREATE TABLE b (name, id) AS
  SELECT 'USD', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'EUR', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OBP', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| DATE | USD | EUR | OBP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-10-28 00:00:00 | 1000 | 2000 | 4000 |
| 2018-10-29 00:00:00 | 2000 | 3000 | 5000 |
| 2018-10-30 00:00:00 | 3000 | 4000 | 6000 |

---

If you actually want to create a table then use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` with one of the above statements (or consider creating a view instead of a physical table).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oKMsn2XB)

Comment: @MTO This question should be solved with the assumption that the number of rows in each of the tables (specifically B) is very large

Comment: @fazi Then when you use the code provided in the answer, you can list all the currencies in your code. In SQL (not just Oracle) it is impossible to generate a static query with a dynamic number of output columns; you **must** generate a known, fixed, number of columns which means that `PIVOT` **must** have a known, fixed number of things it is pivoting by and you need to list them all. The same is true for queries with conditional aggregation; you need to list all the values you are conditionally aggregating with.